# Referring to "title" of <a> in Xpath request

Tags: xpath

I'm making an Xpath as part of a scraping project I'm working on. However, the only defining feature of the text I want is the `title` attribute of the enclosing `<a>` tag like so:

```
<a href="lalala" title="This is what I want to refer to">This is what I want to scrape</a>
```

Is it at all possible to refer to that title and create a path like this?

```
//tr/td[style='vertical-align:top']/a[title='Vacancy details']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes in XPath expressions need to be prefixed with the `@` symbol...

```
//tr/td/a[@title='Vacancy details']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//tr/td/a[@title='Vacancy details']/@title
```

You can grab just the title if that's all you want

Comment: +1 though seems kinda redundant after finding node by exact title match :)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't add a lot of value, but figured it was worth mentioning as a slight variation